# cUrl in Laravel same port is not working in my code

Tags: php, laravel

I'm setting new fitur Login API in my website using cUrl.

When I run in Postman, is working (screnshoot 2). but when i run in my website using cUrl is not working and still loading. if i not set timeout, it will continue to load until infinite time like in screnshoot 1.

[image: image 1 : when i run in my website]
image 1 : when i run in my website

[image: image 2 : when i run in Postman]
image 2 : when i run in Postman

This is my code
Login Controller for proses login from API/cUrl Request

```
public function login()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json(['result' => true, 'message' => "heyho" ], 200);
        // $token =  $user->createToken('nApp')->accessToken;
        // return response()->json(['result' => true, 'message' => $token ], $this->successStatus);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['result'=> false, 'message' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
}
```

This is my code cUrl Process/Request.

```
public function tes()
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_PORT => "8001",
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8001/api/login",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\email@gmail.com\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"password\"\r\n\r\bbbbb\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
            "postman-token: 3546ebed-2016-df32-6d9d-91cdfd43066a"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
    // return url('/')."/api/login";
}
```

Comment: Try remove the port in the `CURLOPT_URL` definition. See the documentation here: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PORT.html

Comment: @DharmaSaputra its not working

Comment: you can not call a post request from web browser

Answer (score 0):

```
Your request is "POST" then how you can see the result in web page 

Only "GET" request only show the results on the web page 

"GET" : In this case we can pass the parameter in the url 
        like : https//:localhost:8000/api/user/1


"POST" : In this case we pass the body in the request body so we need postman to pass the request body"

For more info you can check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
```

Comment: Your answer needs better formatting, and it's also unclear, in my opinion, what your actual answer is.

Comment: ok, sorry for that if you are unable to understand, i want to say that if your request is post method then you need to pass the request body so, how we can pass the request body in url? so, thats why we using the postman